# How to reach Laravel Sail working directory from terminal?

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, laravel-sail, laravel-10

I want to connect my terminal to sail for running commands and edit files in sail containers.

I found that I can execute `php artisan` commands like:
`sail artisan migrate` replacing `php` to `sail`.

But I want to get into: `/var/www/project` in container to execute `php artisan migrate`

What aliases exists for this?

Comment: You can execute commands in the container using something like `docker-compose run <compose container name> <command>` e.g. `docker-compose run web /bin/bash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sail shell` as sail user or `sail root-shell` as root user. Then you can run any command inside the container.

In order to run `php artisan commands` just use `sail shell` then run your commands. However, remember `sail artisan commands` is always there for you.

source: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#sail-container-cli